# Paypal: unable get the response on hitting the url link for get recurring profile details?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

Here is my api url and iam not getting profile details of that particular user in paypal getrecurringprofiledetails can any on help me

```
https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp%20-d%20%22METHOD=GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails&VERSION=117&USER=xxxxxapi1.gmail.com&PWD=xxxxxxxxx&SIGNATURE=xxxxxxxxxxxx&PROFILEID=I-xxxxxx22
```

I am sending the profile id so that I should get profile details of the person assigned with profile id.

The response I am getting from PayPal is:

```
ACK=Failure&L_ERRORCODE0=81002&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Unspecified%20Method&L_LONGME‌​SSAGE0=Method%20Specified%20is%20not%20Supported&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error
```

Comment: What are you getting back from paypal?  What is the code that you are using to send the response? What is the code you are using to receive the response? Thanks.

Comment: iam sending the profile id so that i should get profile details of the person assigned with profile id

Comment: Respons is:`ACK=Failure&L_ERRORCODE0=81002&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Unspecified%20Method&L_LONGMESSAGE0=Method%20Specified%20is%20not%20Supported&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error`

Comment: Lets see if you get some answers now your question has improved a bit. the other thing to include in your question is what have you tried to do so far to fault find / fix it. What have you googled. Include that and your question will get up-votes and be noticed.

Comment: Try this : https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp?METHOD=GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails&VERSION=117&USER=xxxxxapi1.gmail.com&PWD=xxxxxxxxx&SIGNATURE=xxxxxxxxxxxx&PROFILEID=I-xxxxxx22